# Adding a value to a database field that is in your model but is not in your form

Tags: django

I have a model with a property called authID that looks like this:
`authID = models.CharField(max_length=400)`
In my view, all of the fields that are in my form get put into the database as follows:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
  form = PersonalDetailsModelForm(request.POST)
  if form.is_valid():
     form.save()
```

What I want to know how to do is that when they submit the form, I want to also put the value of authID into my database. However, authID is not a field in my form. I don't want to make it a hidden field either for security reasons.
How do you add a value to a database field that **is** in your model, but **is not** in your form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the [`save()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) on `PersonalDetailsModelForm` to set this value before saving the instance:

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    self.instance.authID = 'some_value'   # Set the auth ID
    return super().save(commit=commit)
```

If the `authID` is coming from your view, then you can pass that as a keyword argument to your overridden `save()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Call the **`save()`** method of Django Form with ***`commit=False`***

```
#views.py
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = PersonalDetailsModelForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        model_instance = form.save(commit=False) # 'commit=False' plays key role here
        model_instance.authID = 'your auth id'
        model_instance.save()
        ...
```

### Reference

1. [**Django model form `save()` method**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method)